# Mailkit use of resource image with LinkedResources.Add

Tags: mailkit

Trying to use a resource image:

```
    var builder = new BodyBuilder();

    var image = 
    builder.LinkedResources.Add("pack://application:,,,/Resources/LOGO_275.png");
    image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
```

but needs a string (filename:)

How can i use a resource image ?

Kind Regards

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder();

using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("LOGO_275.png")) {
    var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add("LOGO_275.png", stream);
    image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
}
```

The Add() methods that take a string filename *and* a Stream only use the filename string to figure out the MIME-Type and set the filename property of the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `NameSpace.Resources.Resource.ext` otherwise `GetManifestResourceStream()` returned `null`

```
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WPF_Bestelbons.Resources.LOGO_275.png"))
```